# Hook procedure makes programs crashing

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I want to receive and handle user-selected program messages. Setting a hook on that program works. But when I press any key in the hooked window, then it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
HWND hwnd; // main window handle
HWND rHwnd; // window handle of another process
HHOOK hHook; // hook handle    

// hook procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK HProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
{
    if(code < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);

    if(wParam == VK_RETURN) // show a message after pressing "Enter"
        MessageBox(NULL, "I am hooked!", "", 0);

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}

// somewhere in the main window procedure
rHwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "test program");
// ...
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, HProc, LoadLibrary("user32.dll"), GetWindowThreadProcessId(rHwnd,NULL));
```

Comment: Your call to `SetWindowsHookEx` is horribly wrong. The hook procedure *cannot* be in `user32.dll`. You didn't write that DLL, Microsoft did. Do be sure to read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx).

Comment: More importantly, it seems that you're only hooking *your* application. That doesn't make much sense. You don't need a keyboard hook to handle keyboard events that occur inside of your own application. You just write code inside the application's message loop. Avoid hooks whenever possible, they are like using a bazooka to kill flies.

Comment: You were right - I was calling that function incorrect, but I don't know how to hook other applications.

Comment: Create a dll that exports the HProc function. And then `auto hookdll = LoadLibrary("your-hook.dll"); auto hproc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hookdll, "HProc"); SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, hproc, hookdll, GetWindowThreadProcessId(rHwnd,NULL));`